# Фильтровать элементы массива с нечетным индексом

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать функцию , которая возвращает новый массив, в котором содержатся только те элементы, которые обладали нечетным индексом в массиве, переданном в качестве аргумента. Например:

```
extractOddItems([0,1,0,1,0,1]); // [1,1,1]
extractOddItems([1,2,3,4,5]); [2, 4]
```

Вот я реализовал так

```
// Отфильтровать элементы массива с нечетным индексом
// Реализовать функцию extractOddItems(arr), которая возвращает новый массив, в котором содержатся только те элементы,
// Которые обладали нечетным индексом в массиве, переданном в качестве аргумента. Пример работы:
var a1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // [1,1,1]
var a3 = [];
function extractOddItems(a1,a3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        if (i & 1 ) {
        }
        a1.splice(i,1);
    }
    return a1;
}
extractOddItems(a1);
```

Но программа которая проверяет пишет следующее:

Функция изменяет значения аргументов, хотя не должна. Ожидалось, что после вызова такого кода:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, [], {}];
var oddArr1Items = extractOddItems(arr1);
```

В переменной arr1 массив не изменится, и останется таким:

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, [], {}]

Не могу врубить как сделать так как она хочет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newArr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90].filter(function(v,i){
    if(i % 2 != 0) return v;
});
console.log(newArr); //  [20, 40, 60, 80]
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще так можно:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var res = [];
for(var i=1,l=arr.length;i<l;i+=2){
  res.push(arr[i]);
}
```

`filter` быстро работает только в IE :)

- http://jsperf.com/for-vs-filter
- http://jsperf.com/for-vs-filter-simple